# How do I add two Flags counts to a a single view?

Tags: views, flags

I'm looking for a method where I can have two flag counts in the same view. For example: I would like to list Authors, with a count of how many other people 'follow' them, and at the same time I would like to display the number of nodes that the author has 'bookmarked'. I'm struggling to find away to do this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!